# (Nuxt 3) Computed property from Pinia store doesn't affect the template

Tags: nuxtjs3, computed-properties, pinia, vue-reactivity

I have some pinia stores, like this:

```js
export const common = defineStore('common', {
  state: () => ({
    banner: null,
    ...
  }),

  getters: {
    hasBanner(state) {
      return !!state.banner
    },
  },
})
```

Which are combined into a class that is available in the application through the DI container

```js
import { common } from '~/stores/common'

export default class Store {
  readonly _common

  constructor() {
    this._common = common()
  }

  get common() {
    return this._common
  }
}
```

So i use them in the application in this manner:

```js
<template>
  <div class="layout layout--default" :class="layoutClassObj">
    <nuxt-page />    

    <client-only>
      <app-banner v-if="hasBanner" :data="banner" />
    </client-only>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const { banner, hasBanner } = storeToRefs(useNuxtApp().$app.store.common)

const layoutClassObj = computed(() => ({
  'has-banner': hasBanner.value
}))
</script>
```

And everything works fine as long as we are on the client. On initial page load on this layout, the value of the computed property `layoutClassObj` is ignored in the template, i don't see class `has-banner` on my layout root element.

Banner data is loaded and put into pinia storage via `useAsyncData` method in a child page component.

I see in the developer tools that all values are as they should be, the banner is there, the styles object is calculated correctly. Also all values are recalculated correctly when i close the banner (the value in the storage becomes null).

Also `onTrack` and `onTrigger` callbacks of `layoutClassObj` shows that the banner data comes as a reactive dependency change before rendering, as it should be, because it is received on the server side.

I also note that the banner itself is displayed, despite the fact that it depends on the same computed property as the layout class.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is your getter being invalid. Using the `state` object it should be defined with an arrow function like this:

```js
hasBanner: (state) => {
  return !!state.banner
}
```

It can also be done in this function-like way of yours, but then it has to be written slightly different using `this` instead of `state`:

```js
getters: {
  hasBanner() {
    return !!this.banner
  },
}
```

or, if you're using TypeScript, like this (with explicit return type):

```js
getters: {
  hasBanner(): boolean {
    return !!this.banner
  },
}
```

Docs: https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/getters.html

Comment: Thanks, but I checked, all three options are equivalent and all work the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that the layout itself, as a component, did not react to changes in the underlying components after mounting.
The solution was to add a key to the root element of the layout and replace it in the `onMounted` hook.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).